# 500 error page nginx

Tags: nginx, custom-error-pages

Over the last days I've been trying to get a 500 page to work, first I had used the same thing I used with error 404 but that didn't work, and I think it's because it's a .php file

```
error_page 404 /errors/404.php;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /errors/500.php;
```

Is there any way to use a php file as the 500 error or do I have to create a "500.html" and replicate all the code to be a similar page to the website?

To create a 500 error I used:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.soc;
instead of fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
```

With the 500.html the error appears, but with the .php it doesn't, this one is logic, because i change the config to run php files, but in php errors doesn't work either.

edit:

domain.com.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com;

    root   /var/www/domain.com/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    error_page 404 /errors/404.php;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /errors/500.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

500.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <?php include_once '../meta.php'; ?>
                <?=meta500?>
                <?php include_once '../header.php'; ?>
                <title><?=title500?></title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <?php include_once("../analyticstracking.php") ?>
                <?php include_once '../nav.php'; ?>
                <?php include_once 'containerError500.php'; ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

This works with the 404 page and all the others pages.

Comment: if php itself is blowing up (bad config option) then using a .php script as your error handling page won't work - the error handler would blow up as well, causing further errors. check the error log to see what's causing the 500.

Comment: @Marc B - I think you may want to post this as the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not getting any error, I was just trying to know if it was possible to use a .php file as the 500 error, because it it was possible I could replicate my entire design with includes instead of replicate the entire code on 500.html file.
But I guess that I'll create the html to replicate my design, thanks ;)

Comment: @DanielP Yes, it is possible to use a php file when a 50x error occurs. There must be a problem either with your configuration, or with your php file itself, like Marc B suggested. We could tell you more if you provided both the complete Nginx configuration and the contents of the php file.

Comment: @IvanTsirulev I edited the post with the configuration and the php file